# C - getopt_long not parsing all arguments?

Tags: c, getopt, getopt-long

I am writing the following code for a command called `fp` which exists within a framework for handling these commands that's already in place. I'm fairly new to C and I'm trying to parse some the arguments for this command using getopt_long(). Currently the arguments don't do anything other than print the arguments name and increment a variable to see how many of them were recognized by getopt. Here is the relevant code:

```
//Define options for getopt_long
int opt = 0;
static struct option long_options[] = {
  {"watchdog_timer", optional_argument, NULL, 'w'},
  {"emergency_hold", optional_argument, NULL, 'e'},
  {"braking_wait", optional_argument, NULL, 'r'},
  {"pusher_timeout", optional_argument, NULL, 't'},
  {"pusher_state_accel_min", optional_argument, NULL, 'a'},
  {"pusher_state_min_timer", optional_argument, NULL, 'm'},
  {"pusher_distance_min", optional_argument, NULL, 'd'},
  {"primary_braking_accel_min", optional_argument, NULL, 'b'},
  {NULL, 0, NULL, 0}
};

//Parse arguments
int long_index = 0;
int test = 0;
while ((opt = getopt_long(argc, argv, "wertamdb",
              long_options, &long_index )) != -1){
  switch (opt){
    case 'w':
      note("w");
      test++;
      break;
    case 'e':
      note("e");
      test++;
      break;
    case 'r':
      note("r");
      test++;
      break;
    case 't':
      note("t");
      test++;
      break;
    case 'a':
      note("a");
      test++;
      break;
    case 'm':
      note("m");
      test++;
      break;
    case 'd':
      note("d");
      test++;
      break;
    case 'b':
      note("b");
      test++;
      break;
    default:
      return snprintf(outbuf, outbufc, "Invalid Argument(s)\n");
  }
}
return snprintf(outbuf, outbufc, "Args = %d", test);
```

I then run the code that allows me to enter this command and this is the output that I get (any line beginning with `fp` is input, every other line is output:

```
fp -w 1 -e 1 -r 1 -t 1 -a 1 -m 1 -d 1 -b 1
[NOTE] 101
[NOTE] e
[NOTE] 114
[NOTE] r
[NOTE] 116
[NOTE] t
[NOTE] 97
[NOTE] a
[NOTE] 109
[NOTE] m
[NOTE] 100
[NOTE] d
[NOTE] 98
[NOTE] b
Args = 7
fp -w 1 -e 1 -r 1 -t 1 -a 1 -m 1 -d 1 -b 1
[NOTE] 109
[NOTE] m
[NOTE] 100
[NOTE] d
[NOTE] 98
[NOTE] b
Args = 3
fp -w 1 -e 1 -r 1 -t 1 -a 1 -m 1 -d 1 -b 1
[NOTE] 100
[NOTE] d
[NOTE] 98
[NOTE] b
Args = 2
fp -w 1 -e 1 -r 1 -t 1 -a 1 -m 1 -d 1 -b 1
[NOTE] 98
[NOTE] b
Args = 1
fp -w 1 -e 1 -r 1 -t 1 -a 1 -m 1 -d 1 -b 1
Args = 0
fp -w 1 -e 1 -r 1 -t 1 -a 1 -m 1 -d 1 -b 1
Args = 0
fp -w 1 -e 1 -r 1 -t 1 -a 1 -m 1 -d 1 -b 1
Args = 0
fp -w 1 -e 1 -r 1 -t 1 -a 1 -m 1 -d 1 -b 1
Args = 0
fp -w 1 -e 1 -r 1 -t 1 -a 1 -m 1 -d 1 -b 1
Args = 0
fp -w 1 -e 1 -r 1 -t 1 -a 1 -m 1 -d 1 -b 1
Args = 0
```

For some reason, getopt seems to recognize fewer and fewer of the of the arguments the more times the command is entered. I also double checked to make sure all of the arguments are coming through in argv. Any idea what may cause this? Like I said I haven't worked much with C and I expect this to be something simple I'm missing.

Comment: Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: The "code that allows you to enter this command" may be relevant. Are you resetting `optind`?

Comment: @aschepler — if the OP is processing the arguments multiple times in a single invocation of the program, your point would be very valid, and different option parsing functions provide different mechanisms for doing the reset.  My impression is that he is invoking the program multiple times, as if from a shell script, in which case that won’t be an issue.  But it isn’t clear.  An MCVE ([MCVE]) would help enormously.

Comment: More code needed.  Any chance you are not resetting globals or using uninitialized memory or some other UB?  The other possibility is your OS or framework or whatever is running it is leaking memory over time and causing issues.  Running in your debugger would also probably help a bunch.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'm currently adding this to  code that was written by someone else so mostly I was just looking to see if I had done something wrong I was unaware of in this particular piece of code or if I should consult the original author. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue ended up being that `optind` was not being reset between calls of the command. To fix it I simply added `optind = 0` above the while loop.